# how to put the console value which comes from button clicks, into array format on click of other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple concept here.I am getting some values on clicks of a button in my console,which comes as increment index++,but I need to combine those values into comma separated array format on click another button.I am getting the values in console on click first button,but when I click second button for combine, it showing  undefined.Here is code below.

### html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button> </div>
<div><button id="garray" class="button1">genarete-array</button> </div>
```

### script

```
    var index = 0;
    var id;

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        index++;
        var id = 'chart' + index
        console.log(id);
    });

$('#garray').on('click', function() {
var x = [];
x.push(id);
console.log(x);
//output ['chart1','chart2','chart3','chart4']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have this code:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    index++;
    var id = 'chart' + index
    console.log(id);
});
```

And in particular this line:

```
var id = 'chart' + index
```

That is declaring a new *local* variable called `id`, not updating the *global* variable `id`. To fix it, just change that line to this:

```
id = 'chart' + index
```

Further reading:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope
2. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're **declaring again** the var id, you just need to declare ("var id") once and whenever you want to use, you just use "id = somevalue", the 2nd problem is that everytime you clicks in the 1st button, you're overwriting it's value, the code bellow do what you want:

```
  var index = 0;
    var id = [];

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        index++;
        id.push('chart' + index)
        console.log('chart' + index);
    });

$('#garray').on('click', function() {
console.log(id);
//output ['chart1','chart2','chart3','chart4']
})
```

it's working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/g0xbma5o/

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I need on more help can I get this type of output in console [$('#chart1'), $('#chart2'),$('#chart3')]; because I need to use in some dynamic chaart

Comment: yes, check it again: http://jsfiddle.net/g0xbma5o/1/ and please help, vote on my answer :)

Comment: output is coming now ["$('chart1')", "$('chart2')", "$('chart3')"] ,but  I need like this   [ $('#chart1'), $('#chart2'),$('#chart3')];

Comment: yes, but when you loop in id array you will get what you want, if you get the first index of id (id[0]) you will receive $('#chart1') :)

Comment: I din't get you

Comment: It's already doing it, because $('#chart1') is a **string**, when it's inside an array it will be shown with quotes, can you test my code in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this here

```js
 var index = 0;
    var id;
    var x=[];

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        index++;
        var id = 'chart' + index;
        x.push(id);
        console.log(id);
    });

$('#garray').on('click', function() {

console.log(x);
//output ['chart1','chart2','chart3','chart4']
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button> </div>
<div><button id="garray" class="button1">genarete-array</button> </div>
```